# Happy 3501.ToString("X") day!

Tags: c#, syntax, hex

In C#, is there a way to convert an int value to a hex value without using the .ToString("X") method?

Comment: Some context would be nice. Why can't you use `ToString("X")`?

Comment: Your question example is wrong. After using a dot/fullstop on a number, the decimals are expected. The correct version is `(3501).ToString("X")`.

Comment: @Vercas: no, his code works fine in C#.

Comment: @Sven- the context being... since a hexadecimal value is not a string data type, it seems counter intuitive to call .ToString . With that in mind, I thought there may exist another way to convert/cast an int to its equivalent hex. Also, I felt the need to make a shout out to the dads out there in context of today's holiday. Sorry for the cheeze :)

Comment: @Jed: I'm not sure I see your point. A number is a number until it's displayed. It's usually represented in binary on a computer but you don't need to care. The "hex value" has no meaning until you try to display it, i.e. convert it to a string (well, you can also convert it to an array where each array item is a digit of the number, but I doubt that that's what you want). The father's day reference is cute though. :)

Comment: @Sven it really does not work for me.

Comment: @Vercas it really does work for me. :S

Comment: @Sven it works on my laptop but not on my desktop... It must be an extension's fault...

Comment: @Sven - You're confused at my point because I was confused at what a "hex value" is. As I mentioned in my comment to @InBetween, I was mistaken in thinking that a hex value was an integral data type. Thanks to you guys, I see the light ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is plain wrong (no offense intended). A number has **one** single value. *Hex, Decimal, Binary, Octal*, etc. are just different representations of one same integral number. `Int32` is agnostic when it comes to what representation you choose to *write* it with.

So when you ask:

> is there a way to convert an int value to a hex value

you are asking something thast doesn't make sense. A valid question would be: `is there anyway to write a integer in hexadecimal representation that doesn't involve using .ToString("X")?`

The answer is not really. Someway or the other (directly or not by you), `.ToString("X")` or some other flavor of `ToString()` will be called to correctly format the string representing the value.

And when you think of hexadecimal as a respresentation (a formatted string) of a given number, then `.ToString()` *does* make sense.

Comment: +1 in agreement. 3501 and 0x0dad are how we represent the same value as strings in our source code. To the computer, it's 110110101101, and even that's just a string representation that just happens to be closest to the physical one.

Comment: I agree with you, however when I'm debugging something, especially things like bit-wise manipulation, it's very helpful to see the binary representation of an integer quickly... Which is where Convert.ToString() comes in very handy.

Comment: @Brandon Moretz: Absolutely true, if binary representation is what you are looking for (octal too I think), you can not do it directly through `Int32.ToString(...)`.

Comment: @Jed: That is precisely where you are mistaken. You are not converting the data type. A `int` is a `int` no matter how you represent it (hex, binary, decimal, etc). You are not converting data types at all: `i = 14, i = 0x0E, i = 16 (octal) or i = 0000 1110` are all the same number **and** the same data type (`int`). They are just strings formatted in different ways to represent the same number. (Jed, your comment somehow dissapeared)

Comment: (no offense taken) .. thanks for the clarification! Up 'til now, I was thinking of a hexadecimal value as though it was an integral data type (just as an int, decimal, short, etc are integral types). I suppose I never really considered that a hex value is nothing more than a way of representing a value for an integral type (i.e. it's just a number). Embarrassing :\

Answer (score 2):

Use [Convert.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx)( intValue, 16 );

It can be used to convert between any **common** numeric base, i.e., binary, octal, decimal and hexadecimal.

Comment: Only to/from bases 2, 8, 10, and 16.

Comment: Base64? I was just nit-picking the use of "any base". **:)** *(I did once -- long ago and to teach myself how bases work -- write something for converting from any base in a range to any other base in that range. I think it was just 1 to 36 at the time, though.)*

Comment: @Joel Not to nit-pick, but Base32 and Base64 don't have a universal alphabets (both have multiple variations on what characters are chosen to represent values). So you'd have to specify a custom encoding table when working with converting these. But point taken, :)